# Jquery for making DIV visible/invisible

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I am planning to show a tree structure and on clicking the tree structure I wanted a grid to be displayed. Since I have to show a prototype, I am thinking of using Jquery to show the following

> Application1 (Onclick)
>
> - Display a `<DIV>` with data (similar to a grid)
>
> Application 2 (Onclick)
>
> - Collapse Application 1 `Div` (invisible)
> - Application 2 `DIV` (visible)

so on..

Is there any example that is available that I can use to simulate this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a real basic example:  http://jsfiddle.net/YBABG/1/

```
<div class="parentNode a1">Application 1
    <div class="childNode">Information</div>
</div>
<div class="parentNode a2">Application 2
    <div class="childNode">Information</div>
</div>


$(".childNode").hide();

$(".parentNode").click(function(){
   $(".childNode").hide(100);
   $(this).children().show(100);
});
```

Specifying a duration in hide will create a simple animated effect.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery's [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) methodswill allow you to accomplish your goal.

```
$( 'your_selector' ).click( function() {
    $( '#application_1' ).hide();
    $( '#application_2' ).show();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

JQuery's hide but **doesn't remove the space** and show

```
$("#id").css({ visibility: 'hidden' }) // hidden element (not remove space)
$("#id").css({ visibility: 'visible' }) // show element
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the div elements already exist on the page and you are just toggling their visibility:

```
$('#Application1').click(function() {
  $('#Application1Div').show();
  $('#Application2Div').hide();
});
$('#Application2').click(function() {
  $('#Application2Div').show();
  $('#Application1Div').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here

### [improved DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/BRvJA/1/)

HAVE FUN & Happy coding!

Comment: I am probably going to use this one in the application. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, glad you like it. if you have some questions just write here.

Comment: how can Iam trying to simulate a tree structure. In the demo sample you have mentioned If I click on first div it opens up then if I click it again it should collapse. Is this easily achievable?

Comment: thank you so much! In the new code however I see the DIV being merged together when I click. Yes Since you have followed up with me I want to mark this as answer. I have given it a vote already! Please let me know. Once again thank you.