# How to Show Div When No Result are Found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I search something in a search field and there are no matches, I want to display my div with the ID `error`. I am using jQuery and the isotope plugin.

Here is the code:

```js
$(function() {

  var $grid = $('#container');
  $grid.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item'
  });

  var filters = []; 

  // BUTTON-SEARCH 
  $('#btn').on('click', function() {
      filters[0] = $('#search')[0].value;
      runFilter();
  });

  var runFilter = function() {
    $grid.isotope({
      filter: function() {
        if (filters[0]) {
          // at least some search text was entered:
          var qsRegex = new RegExp(filters[0], 'gi');

          // if the title doesn't match, eliminate it:
          if (!$(this).find('.content-title').text().match(qsRegex)) {
            return false;
          }
        }
        return true;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: We need more context for this -- could you add what your HTML markup looks like? Seems like the answer will have more to do with the Isotope plugin (https://isotope.metafizzy.co/) than jquery itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's .hide() and .show() functions as mentioned here: [Jquery for making DIV visible/invisible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626825/jquery-for-making-div-visible-invisible)

Just write

```
$('#Error').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

So looking at the [isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/) documentation, there's a function you can use to get the number of filtered elements after you do the filtering.

> **getFilteredItemElements**
>
> Returns an array of filtered item elements in current sorted order.

([source](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#getfiltereditemelements))

So it looks like you could do something like this, after the code you have above.

```js
var resultsCount = $grid.isotope('getFilteredItemElements').length;

if (resultsCount < 1) {
  $('#error').show();
} else {
  $('#error').hide();
}
```

I'd put this in your `runFilter` function, so that it always updates after the filter updates.